# Is there a way to "connect" a python project to a specific conda virtual environment?

Tags: bash, shell, conda

Let's say I have a bunch of conda virtual envs and a much larger bunch of python projects.

Most of the time I reuse the same conda virtual env for multiple projects, because the environments are relatively widely scoped (e.g.: one for Spark, one for deep learning, one for data exploration, etc...).

When inside the directory of a project, I would like to be able to run `conda activate` and have the virtual env that I used to work on that project to automatically activate, without having to specify which one.

The reason for this is that with dozens of different projects, sometimes I forget which env belongs to which specific one.

I know that I can create the virtual environment **inside** the project directory, but it's a non solution for me, as I would end up having multiple clones of the same environment everywhere in my system, which is pretty redundant.

Any idea besides having a `readme.MD` that says "Activate *THIS* specific env" ?

Comment: How about creating a bash script inside each project? Not very different from the `readme.MD` approach though

Comment: @BenjaminRuck yeah that's an idea, but still not too different. At this point I'm even wondering if conda supports this at all, because searching online for this question didn't return any actual result.

Comment: Hmm yes, I tried it ealier and it didn't work. But I have to say I'm also not very good with shell scripting.

Comment: I added [tag:shell] and [tag:bash] tags, since it sounds like "*inside the project directory*" implies this is in a shell. If I'm misinterpreting, feel free to remove them. Otherwise, the question is a bit broad right now - it might help to give a concrete example of how you *enter* a directory and run your project code.

Comment: @merv yeah, I meant from the command line, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on the nature of your projects and how you interact with them. For example, IDE's, like PyCharm, let you set an interpreter on a *per project* basis, which sounds like exactly what you want. For those working in Jupyter, each notebook stores the kernel information, but I don't know of a way to set a default kernel within a folder such that every notebook file opens to that.

As for the BASH script suggestion, that should work with a simple script like

**activate_conda_env.sh**

```bash
conda activate envname
```

but note that one has to *source* it in the current shell

```bash
source activate_conda_env.sh
```

for it to work as intended. Otherwise, doing `bash -l activate_conda_env.sh` would simply launch a subprocess, run the activate in there, and then exit the subprocess, having no effect on the current shell process.

Admittedly, this isn't very automated. However, one can set up scripts to run whenever a particular pattern of directory is entered, some tricks for which can be found in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21363).

Comment: I wouldn't mind having to run the command manually myself. It's just more for future-proofing a project, so that if I open it within one year I don't spend 35 minutes trying to remember which one was the virtualenv that I used for it. And since similar tools like "poetry" allow to specify this in a `pyproject.toml` file, I am suprised that conda doesn't have a similar option.